# Filename vs module in logging module

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Assuming that a python file is named with a `.py` extension, would there ever be a reason that the module listed in the output of the logging module is not the filename itself (minus the extension)? For example:

```
Module (module)             == run
Filename (filename)         == run.py
```

Would be a variation of what I would get when using:

```
%(module)s , %(filename)s
```

Would there ever be a use-case where the above does not hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `logging` module, the `module` string is [directly derived from the `filename` string](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b738237d6792acba85b1f6e6c8993a812c7fd815/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L317-L322):

```
try:
    self.filename = os.path.basename(pathname)
    self.module = os.path.splitext(self.filename)[0]
except (TypeError, ValueError, AttributeError):
    self.filename = pathname
    self.module = "Unknown module"
```

So, unless you are using custom logging code that alters these values on the log record after the fact, there is never a reason to see `module` as anything other than the base name of the file, without the extension.